# document.forms[0].submit() is not working into IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Below code is not working in IE. What is solution for it ? how can i submit form into IE browser ?

```
function submitForm(url){
    document.forms[0].action= url;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Below is dome code from JSP Page.

```
<html:form action="xxxxx">
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    ....
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td class="wtspace" height="5" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <html:submit styleId="deleteButton" onclick="doSubmit();">Delete</html:submit>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </html:form>
```

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Unable to check. It is redirecting to login page.

Comment: Put a debug point and check

Comment: Member not found. It is giving to line document.forms[0].submit();

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code too?

Comment: <html:form action="xxxxx">
  <tr>
   <td >&nbsp;</td><td >&nbsp;</td>
  </tr> ....
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
   <td class="wtspace" height="5" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
    <html:submit styleId="deleteButton" onclick="doSubmit();">Delete</html:submit>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </html:form>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125067/discussion-between-david-r-and-rbp).